# difference between initialization for statement counter before and in for?

Tags: c#, for-loop

what is the difference between implementations of the for loop:

between

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{ 
    // code
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the only difference is that you declare and define the variable `i` on the same line. It's rare to see the first example used in actual code bases.

Comment: Which means that the *scope* of that variable also changes

Comment: Correct, but I fail to see how it can be useful to declare the initial expression *outside* of the for statement.

Comment: It could be useful to access the loop variable after the for-statement if you leave it with a `break;` to know the number of times it has looped. `i` could also "inherit" the initial value from somewhere else. But, you are right, I have never seen such a usage.